# adding zero values to 1-D array and fitting it in 2D array so that no error is thrown

Tags: python, numpy

i have 1-D arrays of variable sizes inside a for loop and i'm putting these arrays in rows of a 2d array which is of size 40x4000. How can i append zeros to the end of the 1-D array such that the final size becomes 1x4000 and its able to fit in the 2d array?

eg.

```
size of 1-D: 3700 , so add 300 zeros at the end
size of 1-D: 3800 , so add 200 zeros at the end

for i in range(n)
   s = func(i) #returns row vector
   # what to do here?
   two_dim[i] = s
```

EDIT: these are numpy arrays and not lists

Comment: By array you mean list?

Comment: numpy array. im new to python.

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention that you need a `numpy.array`. Would be helpful to other people if you do that. I answered it for a `list` but had to delete it.

Comment: See if my answer is what you need. Edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this for a smaller input, hopefully this is what you're looking for.

For an initial list `testList = [9, 9, 9, 8, 4, 5]`

```
>>> maxListLen = 10
>>> testList = testList+[0]*(maxListLen-len(testList))
[9, 9, 9, 8, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Since the OP is looking for the `numpy` array.

```
>>> testArray = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> testArray = numpy.append(testArray, [0]*(maxListLen-len(testArray)))
>>> testArray
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped you out. :)